# Can't boot after deleting EFI boot- and Windows-partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I got an HP Split x2 with Windows 8 pre-installed. I deleted it, and installed Ubuntu. However, I was wanting to play a few games that didn't work too well on wine, so I created a NTFS partition and installed Win 7 (UEFI) in it.

Windows was overwriting Grub all the time, and after a tiring struggle, I decided to get rid of Windows 7. I deleted its partition, but UEFI would still try to boot into it, which produced a black error screen ("0xc0000225 - The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible").

I googled a bit, and was told that Windows 7 installs a bootloader in the first partition. Well, I booted from a live CD, and deleted that partition via GParted. Oh, boy. Apparently, that was the EFI Boot partition, and now my laptop won't boot into anything other than live/install USB drives.

I tried boot-repair, and it told me to create an EFI partition, which I have no idea how to.

Is this fixable? Do I have to format my entire hard drive? The Ubuntu partition is still there (according to GParted), it is just not accessible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this was tiring, but I fixed it. Here's how:

1. Create a partition (FAT, first one in hdd, boot flag, 200MiB) via GParted on Ubuntu 14.04 live USB.
2. Use ALT Linux Rescue / rEFInder live USB to boot into my Ubuntu installation (http://en.altlinux.org/Rescue).
3. Follow the instructions at ([an error occurred while mounting /boot/efi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282856/an-error-occurred-while-mounting-boot-efi)) to fix UUIDs.
4. Run boot-repair (http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/).
5. Reboot the PC.

Thanks for trying to help me, hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problem, and you try to enter tty, and enter this in terminal:

```
      sudo apt-get install --force-yes shim-efi-amd64   shim-efi shim-generic
```

and then enter this in tty:

```
     grub-install 
     update-grub2 
     grub-mkconfig
```

and then enter this in the tty:

```
     sudo apt-get update 
     sudo apt-get install - - reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

and then enter this in the tty:

```
     sudo dpkg - - reconfigure - a
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: By "tty" you mean the Terminal? Because it produces an error:
E: Unable to locate package shim-amd64-efi
E: Unable to locate package shim-amd64
E: Unable to locate package shim-amd64-generic
Keep in mind I'm on a live usb, and I've updated my repository in settings already. Sorry for my ignorance, lol.

Comment: You are not online.

Comment: Yes I am, I am posting from that machine right now (live usb). That is not the problem, I think.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **try to make some backups** guys, if you don't know how to, search for it first. obviously i didn't, i already had made backups, months before this self-made disaster happened. But don't blame me if you mess things up.

Check here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition.
It **might work for you as it is**, but I had to format that boot partition to FAT32 (instead of ext4) and label it to boot,esp in manage flags before using the recommended option in boot-repair, yep that's the one I used.
Good Luck!